# How do I validate content inside a .txt file before it gets uploaded to server?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, webforms

I have the following validation expression that I would like to use to validate the content inside .txt files that users try to upload using a web form: `^\s*[1-9][0-9]*\s*(?=([., \t]))(?:\s*(?:\1|\r?\n)\s*[1-9][0-9]*)+\s*$`

How can I validate the .txt file before it gets submitted using this validation expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way files are handled differently than other content in post forms, javascript does not have direct access to file contents before or after upload.

Server side validation paired with user prompts for bad formatting issues (or better, server side fault-resistant file parsing) would address your issue in a technically feasible way.

Comment: how can I setup server side fault resistant file parsing? I'm using Microsoft Azure to host my web app (webform)